# Is $\int_{0}^{\infty} \log (1+ 2\operatorname{sech}x)\,\mathrm dx$ convergent?

Tags: convergence-divergence

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \log (1+ 2\operatorname{sech}x)\,\mathrm dx$$

Comparison test isn't helpful in finding the convergence, besides I can't really find the point of discontinuity.

Comment: *Hint.* For $x \geq 0$ we have $0 \leq \log(1 + 2\operatorname{sech} x) \leq 4 e^{-x}$.

Comment: As you see from the comments and answer the questions was solved, but maybe you want to see it with this code `int log(1+2sech x)dx, from x=0 to infinite` using [Wolfram Alpha online calculator.](https://www.wolframalpha.com) Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x\to \infty$, Sangchul Lee gave the good hint.

Now, close to $x=0$, by Taylor
$$\text{sech}(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ $$1+2\text{sech}(x)=3-x^2+O\left(x^4\right)$$ $$\log\left(1+2\text{sech}(x) \right)=\log (3)-\frac{x^2}{3}+O\left(x^4\right)$$